# MatDatePicker wrong timezone

Tags: angular, google-chrome, angular-material

I have 2 mat-datepickers that return different timezones

I tried to change my timezone in Google to Tokyo and everything worked fine but with Europian locations it returns Standard Time for one date picker and Summer Time for second. I don't have any properties on neither mat datepicker nor anything else that changes timezone so how to fix it?